# Is a bunted foul ball for strike 3 a dead ball?

Tags: baseball

So figure that a batter has 2 strikes on him and bunts the ball foul for strike 3 is the ball still in play since it is considered a strikeout?

Answer (score 4):

According to Rule 5.06(c)5:

> The ball is dead and runners advance one base, or return to their bases, without liability to be put out, when:
>
> - A foul ball is not caught, in which case runners return to their bases.

This is also the reason why pitchers often will not attempt to bunt on two strikes: a foul bunt is a dead ball and strike three.

Answer (score 3):

Any foul ball is a dead ball if it is not caught. This is covered under Rule 5.06(c)(5) in the [2016 MLB Rule Book](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2016/official_baseball_rules.pdf).

> The ball becomes dead and runners advance one base, or return to
>   their bases, without liability to be put out, when:
>
> - A foul ball is not caught, in which case runners
>     return to their bases.